# Intermediate value Theorem for Curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, tangent-line, implicit-function-theorem

I am stuck on this problem from a previous exam.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ function.

Assume:

1. $C=\{f(x,y)=0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a path-connected curve.
2. $\forall (x,y) \in C : f'|_{(x,y)}\neq 0$.
3. $C$ is tangent to the $\hat{x}$-axis at $(1,0)$, and to the $\hat{y}$-axis at $(0,1)$.

Prove:

C is tangent to a line $x+y=d$ for some $d\in \mathbb{R}$.

Using the Implicit Function Theorem I have derived that $gradf|_{(1,0)} = (0,\alpha)$, and $gradf|_{(0,1)} = (\beta,0)$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to use the Intermediate Value Theorem but I can't figure out which function to use, since $\alpha, \beta$ are not necessarily of the same/opposite signs.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Cauchy Mean Value Theorem. Assume that you can parametrize $C$  differentiably by $(f(t),g(t))$, $0\le t\le 1$, with $(f(0),g(0)) = (1,0)$ and $(f(1),g(1)) = (0,1)$. I think the hypotheses on the tangencies at the two points are unneeded.

Comment: Thanks! How can I deduce that $g'(t) \neq 0$ along the curve?

Comment: You actually don't need to do that (and it needn't be true), if you write the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem without quotients in it :P The more serious question is that you cannot conclude from the Implicit Function Theorem that you have a global parametric representation of the curve. It's hard to answer this without knowing exactly what equipment you have to handle the question. You put the differential geometry tag here. Do you know facts from the differential geometry of curves? If so, what?

Comment: I think I mistakenly attached the differential geometry tag, because I didn't really understand the concept till now. Guess I was lucky to do that because I got your attention on this post! Could you provide me with a solution based on tools from a standard (mathematics-major) multivariable calculus course?

Comment: I already gave you the easiest approach I can think of. I don't know what your professor has in mind.

Comment: Thanks. Here are his solutions for those interested (Question 2.b) https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~kernerdm/Teaching/2019.Geom.Calculus.1/2020.02.06.Moed.A.Infi.1.Solutions.pdf